# Запоздание изменения позиции тача

Tags: unity3d, drag-n-drop, touch

Использую метод

```
 public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
            m_VerticalVirtualAxis.Update( eventData.delta.y);
            m_HorizontalVirtualAxis.Update( eventData.delta.x);

    }
```

для изменения виртуальных осей. В редакторе все хорошо работает, но на девайсе, после того как палец изменился, то через долю секунды происходит пересчет position (точки касания) и delta меняет знак. Как быть с этим?

Answer (score 0):

В зависимости от того какой тач стоит на устройстве его точность может сильно различаться. Чтобы бороться со случайными срабатываниями заводили у себя `DeadZone` где было прописано значение `[0-1]`, скажем `0.1f` или доля экрана, в пределах которого смещение не учитывалось